# Strange BUG in C++ iostream?

Tags: c++, iostream

is this a bug in iostream? ...

```
        #include<iostream>
        void money_conversion (){

        constexpr double dollars_in_yen=0.01;
        constexpr double dollars_in_euro=1.16;
        constexpr double dollars_in_pound=1.33;
        std::cout<<"Supported valutes : yen ('y'), euros('e'), pounds('p').\n";
        std::cout<<"Please enter the value + valute that you want to convert into dollars! :";
        double value=1;
        char valute=0;
        while(true){
        std::cin>>value>>valute;
        if(valute=='y')
            std::cout<<"\n\n"<<value<<" yens is "<<value*dollars_in_yen<<" dollars. \n";
        else if(valute=='e')
            std::cout<<"\n\n"<<value<<" euros is "<<value*dollars_in_euro<<" dollars. \n";
        else if(valute=='p')
            std::cout<<"\n\n"<<value<<" pounds is "<<value*dollars_in_pound<<" dollars. \n";
        else
            std::cout<<"\n\nSorry, unknown valute ("<<valute<<").\n";
        }

    }


    int main(){

        money_conversion();
        return 0;

    }
```

When keyboard input is

- '5p' or
- '5 p' or
- '3y' or
- '3 y' or
- '1 z' or
- 1z' or
- '10 e'

everything goes as expected.

When the input is `'(anyting)e'` its an error (like `'5e'`)
I have tryied pretty much everything to try to make it work but no success.

When i remove `while()` loop i get this output when entered  `'5e'` -> 
`"Sorry, unknown valute ( )"` but when i enter lets say `'7m'` i get output `"Sorry, unknown valute (m)."`

I make of this a big deal because, in large code, this can be an error that is almost impossible to notice.
Is `'e'` a problem as `char` input in some cases?

Comment: I guess `e` is parsed as a part of floating point exponent.

Comment: yep, '5e2' is as '500' so its missing the rest of input and thats why it becomes infinite loop. thanks, God bless

Comment: @tobi303 reading `7m` as double is well-defined: it should read `7` and leave `m` in the stream

Comment: @M.M oh really? Then I learned something ;)

Comment: Rule of thumb: when the question is "is there a bug in this library used by millions of people", the answer most likely is "no". I still use that assumption after 20 years in C++.

Comment: @MSalters ill get back to you on this one ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is **not** a bug in the C++ stream classes.

You need to read in the input as a `std::string` and extract the value and the currency yourself.

That's because `e` is used to separate the *significand* and the *exponent* in *scientific notation*, which is another way of specifying a `double`. Threfore `10e` is an invalid `double` as it's missing the portion that defines the exponent.

By the way, using GBP, EUR, and JPY (which are the ISO codes for the currencies you want to support) would be less idiosyncratic.

Comment: I would recommend extracting an integer, then if the next char is `.`, extract another integer

Comment: Fair point - extract the right character from the current locale :)

Answer (score 5):

When a `std::istream` or `std::locale` library function attempts to parse any numeric input, it always first grabs all contiguous characters in the set `"0123456789abcdefxABCDEFX+-"` and which might be valid for the type of conversion being done, and only then tries to determine what they mean.  See the description of [Stage 2 of the `num_get` processing](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/facet.num.get.virtuals#3).

So in your `"5e"` example, the `operator>>(double&)` function grabs both `'5'` and `'e'`, expecting to find an exponent after the `'e'`, but stops there, and those characters don't make a valid complete `double`.

Comment: i kinda understand what you are saying here but. '5c' input gives legit output : 'Sorry, unknown valute (c).' and no infinite loop error. same as a, b, d, f . only '(number)e' is problem - '5e2e' produces legit output : "500 euros is 580 dollars."

Comment: Hopefully one day we can add `o` to that list if `0o` becomes a prefix for an octal literal.

Comment: You left out a key part of Stage 2: "a check is made to determine if c is allowed as the next character of an input field of the conversion specifier returned by Stage 1."    This rule is why `7a`, `7b` etc. are OK but `7e` is not

Comment: @M.M Thanks, I totally missed that part! Should be more correct now.